# SQL Statement to get list containing one row from all tables?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have data in hundreds of tables in a sqlite database, where one column is a month ("December 2016", "January 2017", etc) and other columns contain data corresponding to that month.

Is there a single SQL statement to return the data where "month = 'December 2016'" for all tables?  I can do it with loops in Python, but it feels like I'm not using SQL to its full potential.

Comment: This sounds as if your database structure is wrong. Can't you change it?

Comment: The structure certainly doesn't fit this query, but most queries pertain to all of the months for one table (particularly differences from month-to-month).  Those queries can be handled very well with SQL statements.  But in some instances I want to look at the values for all tables, for one given month.